# Change Package Name of Windows Store App

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How do we change the package name of a Windows Store App? Please note we do not want to change the app display name.

We have published a UWP app to the Windows Store. Visual Studio generated a package name `<PublisherName>.<AppName>`in the package manifest.

When I changed the package name in the package manifest to a guid and published to the store I got the errors

```
 Invalid package identity name
 Invalid package family name
```

I can see the store app is associated with the package name. Do we have to delete the store app and create a new submission?

Can a UWP store app have a guid for a package name?

Comment: Do you want your app to be published with your app display name in the Store and to get installed with a different app name on local side?

Answer (score 0):

You app identity in Package.appmanifest should be the same as in the store.

Check your app identity in the store:

[image]

Check your Package.appmanifest. Name and Publisher must be same as in store:

[image]

If they are not. Copy Package name from the store in your manifest, and then click Choose Certificate... button. Then select Configure Certificate...->Create test certificate. And copy there your publisher name from the store.

[image]

After that you cag generate your upload package and submit it to the store.

Comment: Thank you @ad1Dima but we want to change the app identity from what it currently is in the store to a guid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've misunderstood the store process. I was incorrect in thinking the app identity was generated by Visual Studio. [The app identity is assigned by the store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/publish/view-app-identity-details).

> If you use Microsoft Visual Studio to build your packages, and are signed in with the same Microsoft account that you have associated with your developer account, these details are included automatically.

So it looks like we will have to live with the app folder being discoverable by users.

Answer (score 0):

**The future package names of a Windows Store App is automatically generated by the MS Store, made from the Contact info Publisher display name (and the Appname as the second name)**, when the partner account is registered (nobody told me that before, haven't seen it in the MS documentation).

**I made the mistake to set Companyname Ltd, My Name** as the Contact info Publisher display name and got a bad package name of my Windows Store App.

*I got CompanynameLtdMyName.appname as the package name of a Windows Store App, and all non US-ASCII letters just removed making the first package name to a blur. **I actually want my company's internet domain reverse to be the package first name com.Companyname** that is common use elsewhere, and the only good looking solution for non US-ASCII countries publishers. These immaterial issues are quite important in marketing.  **But there is no such package first name field for package names in the MS Store/Partner account settings.***

**And I can't set com.Companyname as the Contact info Publisher display name**, because it isn't. **And I have to settle with Companyname Ltd** that is the legal party (this is civil law topics as well), getting CompanynameLtd.appname as the package name of a Windows Store App, that is acceptable.

**So I tried to change** (settings, the cogwhee) the Contact info Publisher display name to Companyname Ltd and the Appname and it takes a full verification process time to make the change. MS says the verification process can take from a few days to a couple of weeks.

Well I managed to change the Contact info Publisher display name to Companyname Ltd after a few hours. And after that I had to use the second radio box in the Store/Create Your packages "..New app.." and point to the old app, to make it accept the new  Contact info Publisher display name. (It should be right for the civil law.)

**But the MainPackageIdentityName did not change** is still CompanynameLtdMyName.appname and I guess I must register a new app name to get any change.

A perfect world is the perfect boring state of life and I don't have the effort to investigate this more.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this? It looks like a new app submission will not fix your problem. It seems to me that you need to create a new developer / publisher account for the Microsoft Store, although that seems extreme.

Comment: I can't see the Package/Identity/Name appears anywhere except at the MS Partner center, not in the MS Store? Looks bad internally for the supplier. Is it really an issue? Or please tell where I can see it in the public part of MS Store?

Comment: If my app is not working for a specific user, I might have them email me files from the application's Local Folder to check if they are corrupted. Since the client can see the name of the folder in File Explorer during that process, I would prefer to have the folder use my current publisher name, as opposed to the one I used a while ago. It is a minor issue, but an issue nonetheless.

Comment: please tell how anyone else come see the information?

Comment: Open File Explorer, go to:  C:\Users\ [USERNAME] \AppData\Local\Packages and you can see the package name. Most users will never go here. But in the event that a user does, it would be nice if the package display name was correct.

Comment: Thanks! I liked to know. Good argument, lets hope they fix it.

Comment: At least it should look good and the assignments is made with no alerts on its implication and that there is no edit possibility. In fact I made Apple to fix mine there, similar issue (I a one man company, due to Swedish law and wanted to be presented by the company name (who actually makes the business). Corporate/tax law is different in different countries and all is set up for US use. Asked Google play for the same thing and they rejected. It should look good. And a consultant must be able to set up an account for a client. Lets hope MS Store fix it.